# Getting dam asset link by Java on Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia, dam

I'm trying to get an asset link (image), to create an object to use as a return of a rest service.
I got all my object created only missing this link, I can't find any method to use for it on `Java` side. As `FTL` I don't have any problem to do it (using `DamTemplatingFunctions`).
On JCR, on my article (on my own workspace) I got the asset key "`jcr:xxxxxxxx...`" and I can easily acess it, the only part missing is how can I retrieve the link for it from the `dam` workspace.

Thanks for all help or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inject the DamTemplatingFunctions and then use the methods. Here an example how to inject

```
@Inject
public Example(DamTemplatingFunctions damTemplatingFunctions) {
    this.damTemplatingFunctions = damTemplatingFunctions;
}

private DamTemplatingFunctions damTemplatingFunctions;
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to do it using `Components` class like so:
`private static DamTemplatingFunctions damTemplatingFunctions = Components.getComponent(DamTemplatingFunctions.class); `
and then I can use all of the methods

happy coding =}